# How many words, with or without meaning, can be formed by selecting $3$ consonants and $2$ vowels from $7$ consonants and $4$ vowels?

Tags: permutations

There are $7$ consonants and $4$ vowels.  How many words, with or without meaning, can be formed by selecting $3$ consonants and $2$ vowels? Should one consider permutation or combination?

Comment: These are permutations.

Answer (score 1):

> How many words can be formed by selecting $3$ consonants and $2$ vowels?

Assuming that each letter is **unique** and selected **without replacement**:

$$\binom73\cdot\binom42\cdot(3+2)!$$

---

> Should one consider permutation or combination?

As you can understand from the "$(3+2)!$" in the previous answer: permutation.